# Why does switching from a shared lock to an exclusive lock cause a deadlock and rolls back all other blocked transactions?

Tags: mysql, locking, deadlock

I was testing some queries on MySQL 5.7.26 and noticed something strange (?). Why does a deadlock occur when the below commands are entered in the following order:

session 1:

```
start transaction;
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id = 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

session 2:

```
UPDATE test_table set col_1 = "foobar" WHERE id = 1;
# blocks
```

session 1:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

session 2:

```
# displays ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

I ask this because I feel like this is related to something I encountered in a web app I am working on which deals with a child table containing a foreign key to a certain parent table. It goes something like the following and also leads to a deadlock (hopefully it's simple enough to follow):

session 1:

```
start transaction;
INSERT INTO child_table (parent_id, col1) VALUES (1, "a");
```

session 2:

```
UPDATE parent_table SET col2 = "foo" WHERE id = 1;
# blocks, because the insert query in session 1 creates a shared lock on the related parent_table row
```

session 1:

```
UPDATE parent_table SET col2 = "bar" WHERE id = 1;
```

session 2:

```
# displays ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I should read the docs more. An example exists in the link below that is exactly the same as my question

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-example.html

Basically: "Deadlock occurs here because client A needs an X lock to update the row. However, that lock request cannot be granted because client B already has a request for an X lock and is waiting for client A to release its S lock. Nor can the S lock held by A be upgraded to an X lock because of the prior request by B for an X lock. As a result, InnoDB generates an error for one of the clients and releases its locks"